# Can a value in std::map for a key be locked?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a simple std::map having key-value. I want this map to be thread safe. I do not want to lock the entire map. Since my threads would be working(update,delete) only on the values for a particular key in the map, I do not wish to lock the entire map. I want the other threads to be able to work on the map, of course not on the locked value.

Would it be advisable or logically correct to lock only the value for a specific key? OR I should think of another data structure?

Update: I just tried a sample example where i have parallel threads updating and inserting in the same map .

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection; 


struct newEntry
{
    int key;
    char value;
};


std::map<int,char> mapIntChar;

unsigned __stdcall UpdateThreadFunc( void* pArguments )
{

    char *ptr =  (char *) pArguments;
    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection); 
    *ptr = 'Z';
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
    _endthreadex( 0 );
    return 0;
 } 

unsigned __stdcall InsertThreadFunc( void* pArguments )
{
struct newEntry *ptr =  (struct newEntry *) pArguments;
mapIntChar[ptr->key] = ptr->value;
    _endthreadex( 0 );
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::map<int,char>::iterator it1;
    unsigned threadID;
    if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&CriticalSection, 
    0x00000400) ) 
    return 0;
    mapIntChar[0] = 'A';
    mapIntChar[1] = 'B';
    mapIntChar[2] = 'C';
    mapIntChar[3] = 'D';

    HANDLE   hThread;
    int nCount = 0;
    struct newEntry *newIns;
    while ( nCount < 1004)
{
         it1 = mapIntChar.begin();
    char *ptr = &(it1->second);
         hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &UpdateThreadFunc, ptr, 0, &threadID );

         newIns = new newEntry;
         newIns->key = rand() % 1000;
         newIns->value = 'K';
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &InsertThreadFunc, newIns, 0, &threadID );
    nCount++;
         delete newIns;
}
}
```

Comment: By the way, putting spaces *before* sentence signs is bad practice. Just so you know for future machine writings.

Comment: @ChristianRau I'll take care

Answer (score 2):

You could create a wrapper around `std::map` (or rather have the container type as a template parameter, so you can use similar containers like `std::unordered_map` or `std::set`), that have functionality to lock specific entries.

The wrapper class have to mirror the methods in the actual `std::map` class, with their implementations containing checks for the locks but otherwise just call the method in the underlying container type.

Comment: Of course the parallel structure containing the locks would have to be locked as well. You're better off just locking the original map.

Comment: @MArk Yes thats what it the current implementation . However due to resource crunch threads pileup for the access of the map . Hence we want to lock the macro level entries .

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar what I'm saying is that this answer doesn't work. Whatever structure you're using to lock the specific entries will itself need to be locked. You'll have the same problem, just one level of indirection deeper.

Comment: @MarkRansom i have map like map<INT, user defined Object> . The user defined object will be unique for every entry in the map

Answer (score 0):

If the map already has an entry for each key you want to modify, then you should be able to modify the values for these keys on different threads as long as each thread uses a different set of keys with no overlap, *and* as long as nothing modifies the structure of the map itself (i.e. doesn't modify the set of keys in the map, or otherwise resizes it).

That said, technically this is only true for C++11. Before that, C++ pretended threads didn't exist and made no guarantees at all about the memory model when multiple threads were running.

Comment: If a thread adds an entry in the map would it disturb the operation. I thought the sorting/resizing always happens on the key . Since I am locking the value , the key should be able to move around in the map

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar: If the structure of the map doesn't change, then accessing the values on different threads should be safe, as long as two threads don't operate on the same value.

Comment: so u meant to say there shouldnt be any additions or deletions in the map ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar: Correct.

Comment: My understanding was that  insertions and deletions is always done on the Key ...so what might happen if a new key is inserted or deleted from the map

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar: That's why I said don't insert or delete keys.

Comment: I have posted a sample code ...which works without any problem